# Running () on a variable

Tags: dart

A little bit confused by the `d();` notation...
Is it a kind of semantic shugar? The meaning of `d();` should be `call()` as it described in `ReactionDisposer` class. I.e. there should be `d.call();` will it have the same meaning?

```
void dispose() {
    for (final d in _disposers) { // a list of type ReactionDisposer
      d(); // what is it?
    }
  }

class ReactionDisposer {
  ReactionDisposer(this.reaction);

  final Reaction reaction;

  /// Invoking it will dispose the underlying [reaction]
  void call() => reaction.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dart, you can use an object as if it is a method/function if the object implements the method `call()`.

So `d();` will execute the `call()` method defined in `ReactionDisposer`.

You can read about this in the Dart Langauge Tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes